# what do I need to use to change controller when sliding left?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, segue

I want to create a touch control, where I slide left and the view scrolls in a paged mode (like in Photos app where you slide between photos) but instead of a view in a current controller coming in, I want a new controller to come in with it's own view. What control should I use to build something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use UIPageViewController to navigate between different ViewController like a scrollView

You can follow this tutorial

1-http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-storyboard-tutorial/

2-http://www.appcoda.com/uipageviewcontroller-tutorial-intro/

3-http://www.makemegeek.com/uipageviewcontroller-example-ios/

hope it will help you

Comment: I want to know how UIPageViewController handles segues of child controllers. Once I learn and set it up, I am going to find out :)